# Effect of lower average temperatures on the tropical savannahs and deserts of a planet

Tags: science-fiction, climate, alternate-worlds, worldbuilding-process

I have a nagging question that has been eating away at me since I am figuring out the biomes that are present in the world that I am building. For all intents and purposes this world is basically an earth clone in axil tilt and orbit eccentricity with it being an earth with some added spice thrown in. The planet has a 396 day long year with an average temperature of 55 degrees F (12.7 C) during the summer and an average temperature of 50 degrees F (10 C) during the winter months, the world has a greenhouse effect 1.35 times of earth. I also calculated that the world receives roughly 80% of the Earth's Solar radiation intensity due to sitting slightly further away from its sun. I assume that these changes would make the planet more wet with a winter being 5 months long instead of earth's 4 month long winter, but I can't be sure. How do these factors affect the climate of the planet; does this mean that deserts are cooler and savannahs more lush grasslands, or does everything stay basically the same as earth? (Image of landmass position added below, a decent portion of the globe seems to fall into the tropical savanna zone on earth, and the black and white are major mountain chains formed from tectonic activity)[image][image]

Comment: Can we help you narrow this question down? Addressing "the biomes of the planet" violates Stack Exchange's "book rule" (see this [help/dont-ask] page) in that you're asking about every plant, every animal, every bacteria, literally *everything* that constitutes life on a planet. I believe if we can narrow this down to a chunk you'd have enough info to work out the rest, and if not, we can tackle individual problems one-at-a-time. For starters, what about the Alaskan, northern Canadian, and northern Russian climates (and their southern counterparts) don't answer your question?

Comment: Alright edited the question to only deal with the climate of the Savannah and Deserts of the world. Hope this falls more in line with the rules as it narrows down the inquiry.

Comment: That's MUCH simpler. Climate is still quite complicated, but I think the question can be reasonably scoped now. Thanks for the quick edit! +1. Be thinking about showing areas in question  on the map, basic geology (where are the mountains), and some basic sea currents. Those are common requests for climate questions.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll add in a map like that and make those notes then, the map doesn't have sea currents but it shows mountain chains and where the biomes were originally placed.

Comment: By a most fortunate coincidence, Earth itself was a little bit coolder in the not too distant past, say about 20,000 years ago. You may want to research whether during the [Last Glacial Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Glacial_Maximum) the grasslands were more or less lush than at present. (And, anyway, it's nonsensical to speak of a *planet's* average temperature in summer and in winter; when half of the planet is in summer the other is in winter. Second, a planet's average temperature is a meaningless number: averaging the temperatures of Murmansk and Timbuktu is not useful.)

Comment: your map has a few issues, you go from tundra to tropical rainforest within like 10 degrees of latitude. you even have cold steppe right next to tropical rainforest. also planets don't have summer or winter, only hemispheres do. Lastly your planet is barely cooler than the current earth. for comparison the temprature during the last glacial maximum was 46 degrees on average. and the earth ice sheets looked like this https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Global-extent-of-glaciation-during-the-Last-Glacial-Maximum-during-the-Late-Pleistocene_fig9_275040990

Comment: I don't think you understand how seasons work, when it is winter in the norther hemisphere it is summer in the southern hemisphere, If the amount of land distribution is the same the the planets average temprature is the same regardless of the season. Also the season will always bee the same length.

Comment: @John I based the environment map off of Artifexian's videos on it in his world building playlist on how to place biomes based on currents both water and air, but to be fair it wasn't the most in depth or helpful video. The reason for the seasonal temp differences was the orbit where during 5 months of the year the planet is further away from the star than the rest of the year.

Comment: @anthonygutierrez that's not how seasons work, the earth is actually closer to the sun during the northern winter. Also in the future an equator line will make your map a lot easier to read.

Comment: I suggest asking for an assessment of the accuracy of your planet first then working on the climate. also for a planet that is supposed to be wetter you have made it drier with wide spread desert and very little wet biomes. this might be due to your latitudes but without any markers we can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Winter actually tends to be much drier than summer due to moisture not having the energy to remain suspended in the air. Also, frozen water does not evaporate to increase humidity. A good portion of central Antarctica has pretty much zero humidity due to this fact. People living in northern climates will often have humidifiers for wintertime use to decrease nose bleeds. Decreased atmospheric moisture would result in less winter snowfall, which means that melt-water rivers will not last as long before the snow melt runs out. Deserts and savannahs would likely be larger as these areas would receive less water overall. While their overall temperatures might not get as hot, they would not be lusher without more water. Ground water would become a critical resource.

Warmer air holds more moisture. This is why climate scientists have stated that storms will become worse as the planet heats up. Heat evaporates surface water and adds it to the air. Cold causes the moisture to condense out of it. Much of the question about biome formation depends heavily on factors such as humidity, wind speed, local bodies of water, mountain ranges, and jet stream effects. If there is a mountain range which gets snowfall in the winter, it can release this water in the form of rivers and streams throughout the rest (or part) of the year. This water will only go so far, but will travel further if there is less evaporation due to a colder surface temperature. This means that biome formation on your world will rely more on river water distribution than rainfall.

There is also the chance that you will have a near permanent ice-age, with large glaciers forming and mountains remaining snowcapped with little summer melt occurring. White snow reflects light instead of absorbing it. This can prevent melting long into a summer season without hot surface air helping out. It will cause sea levels to fall as ocean water evaporates to become trapped as snow and ice. On the bright side, summer storms would be less of an issue as there would be less energy for hurricanes.

Answer (score -1):

We lack data to say anything definitive. Currently, Earth is warming. The climate models try to analyze the impact, and while they make consistent predictions in many aspects (more hurricanes, more extreme cold/heat events on average), what happens to biomes varies wildly. The Middle East gets everything — desert, jungle, Great Plains. That variance is caused some by terrain but also by life’s reaction to the changes. Life can massively adapt, and depending upon what lives and spreads, the ecology changes wildly. (A dominant grass can save soil/a dominant tree can trap moisture. We see what happens when species are killed today... effects are unpredictable.) So we can say a lot about what the temp/humidity/wind will be, but not much about the ecology.

Ask again in 10,000 years when we have a wider sample size. In the meantime, write what you want!

Comment: Of course we do have *some* data to say what would happen if the average global temperature was a tad lower than the historical average. After all, Earth did go in the recent geological past through extended periods of time when it was both warmer and cooler than now, and we know very well what kind of animals and plants lived where, what was the level of rain and snow etc.

Comment: Paleoclimatology is a thing, just because you don't know doesn't mean nobody knows.

Comment: @John we know what DID happen. We also know what particular thing WILL happen, even given the SAME STIMULUS, is very variable.

Comment: @AlexP Please re-read what I wrote. We can say strong theories about the climate regions that will form, but not the ecologies within those climate regions.

Comment: Its fairly easy to predict the OP is only asking about the biome not a breakdown of every living thing in the community. biomes are reliably predicted by rainfall and temprature. I think you are reading more into the question than what is being asked.

Comment: biome is not climate region. biome: "a large naturally occurring community of flora and fauna occupying a major habitat, e.g. forest or tundra." It is the fundamental type: plains, forest, jungle, tundra, etc. And, no, those are not predictable. Same temp/humidity can result in very different biomes.

Comment: From Britannica Kids: “A biome is a large region of Earth that has a certain climate AND certain types of living things.” So it really is both.

Comment: @DanPar try something better than Britannica kids, "certain types" in that case just means organisms adapted to that climate. the Sahara and the the Mohave are both the same biome despite different wildlife. A temperate forest is a temperate forest even if they don't share a single species in common. Again paleoclimatology exists, predictions are possible.

Comment: @SRM biome location questions are quite common on worldbuilding, it is a very answerable question. Again paleoclimatology exists, predictions are possible. The poster is not asking for anything outside even the recent past ranges so its not even that difficult.

Comment: @John Oh, so that’s what that meant. Thanks for clearing that up!  I do know you can predict climate but that bit confused me.